# Using event listener should we use useCapture as false to support old browser or it will be used as default for every browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecma

I am making a website for an organization who has diverse clients in different countries. How should I use an event listener

```
document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClickOutsideOption)
```

or

```
document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClickOutsideOption, false)
```

to support a vast diversity of clients

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

> **Note:** `useCapture` has not always been optional. Ideally, you should include it for the widest possible browser compatibility.

So yes, you should set it to `false` to support a vast diversity of clients.

Also, you need to know when you might want to set it to `true`. Let's say you are listening for `blur` event on a single input textbox, then you can keep it as `false` like:

```
const blog = document.querySelector('#blog');
blog.addEventListener('blur', function (event) {
    // Your logic here...
}, false);
```

But, if you want to listen to all `blur` events in the `document`, then you should set it to `true` like:

```
document.addEventListener('blur', function (event) {
    // Your logic here...
}, true);
```

As, setting it to `true` help us to take advantage of event bubbling for events that otherwise don't support it like `focus`, `blur`, etc. Basically it is `false` for most used events, thus this param is `optional` in modern browsers and its defaults to `false`.

Comment: after reading your answer, I think I was using it in wrong way. I need to close a component, if there is a click event anywhere on the window. So, should I use true/false for capture/bubbling event?

Comment: It's not needed for click event as click event supports event bubbling. As mentioned in docs, "_Events in the target phase will trigger all listeners on an element in the order they were registered, regardless of the useCapture parameter._"